# Immortal Service

Tags: java, android

I need to implement a project, such as chat. We decided to use the [Socket.IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) library. `FCM` is not considered. To receive messages in the background using `Service`. Here:

```
public class SocketServiceProvider extends Service {

    private Socket mSocket;

    private final String EVENT_NEW_MESSAGE = "new_message";
    private final String LOG_TAG = "SocketServiceProvider";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "created()");
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
        if (mSocket == null)
            mSocket = BaseApplication.getSocket();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStartedCommand()");

        startSocket();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startSocket() {
        if (mSocket.connected()){
            stopSocket();
        }

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        mSocket.on(EVENT_NEW_MESSAGE, onNewMessage);

        mSocket.connect();
    }

    private void stopSocket() {
        mSocket.off();
        mSocket.disconnect();
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
                if (mSocket.connected()) {
                    isOnline = true;
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connected!");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = args -> {
        final JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
        final String username;
        final String message;
        try {
            username = data.getString("from");
            message = data.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, username + " wrote: " + message);
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy()");

        stopSocket();

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, SocketServiceProvider.class));
    }
}
```

The only problem is that when the phone goes into `Doze mode`, messages do not come. Tried to wake up with `AlarmManager` in `onTaskRemoved()`, `onDestroy()`, unsuccessfully.

Even with `onDestroy()` tried to call `BroadcastReceiver`, so that it started back my Service, just did not understand why, but its `onReceive()` method does not work.

Here is my last option, the code that posted. There is I usе `startForegroundService`. And this option worked, at least not dying. Only in this case, the battery discharges quickly

Googled, Write that using `JobIntentService` can be implemented, but nowhere described in detail.

Question: How can this be done and how did you implement such tasks? And how can this be achieved with `JobIntentService`?

Comment: "And how can this be achieved with JobIntentService?" -- it can't. A job can only run for 10 minutes.

Comment: Badum Tssssssss.

Comment: Socket.IO is a bad choice for modern Android.  It would have been ok in the past, but given doze whitelists and everything else trying to prevent long term background services, anything other than FCM is likely a mistake.

Comment: Doze mode is not your only problem, once your app is in background it's at the mercy of the os and other apps and they can easily send your Service to bytecode's heaven